# Invert columns/Change unit of observation

Tags: r, dataframe, panel

I am working with data that looks like this:

```
 CATEGORY PARENT PROPERTY `2018 DOLS` `2018 UNITS` `2017 DOLS` `2017 UNITS`
      xxx     A       P1       100            1          200          2
      xxx     A       P2       NA             NA         200          1
      xxx     B       P3       300            1          NA           NA
```

As you can see, observations in the PARENT column may be repeated several times. I would like to covert this data frame into a panel at the PARENT-YEAR level in the following way:

```
CATEGORY PARENT   YEAR    `P1 DOLS` `P1 UNITS` `P2 DOLS` `P2 UNITS` `P3 DOLS` `P3 UNITS`
   xxx     A       2017       200      2          200          1      0           0
   xxx     A       2018       100      1           0           0      0           0
   xxx     B       2018         0      0           0           0     300          1
```

Notice that essentially this amount to invert columns and road between years and PROPERTY entries (while ignoring NAs).  I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to carry out this task? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('^\\d+'), 
               names_to = c('Year', 'name'), 
               names_sep = '\\s+', 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(PROPERTY, name), values_from = value, 
              values_fill = 0, names_sep = ' ')

# CATEGORY PARENT Year  `P1 DOLS` `P1 UNITS` `P2 DOLS` `P2 UNITS` `P3 DOLS` `P3 UNITS`
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>     <int>      <int>     <int>      <int>     <int>      <int>
#1 xxx      A      2018        100          1         0          0         0          0
#2 xxx      A      2017        200          2       200          1         0          0
#3 xxx      B      2018          0          0         0          0       300          1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CATEGORY = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx"), PARENT = c("A", 
"A", "B"), PROPERTY = c("P1", "P2", "P3"), `2018 DOLS` = c(100L, 
NA, 300L), `2018 UNITS` = c(1L, NA, 1L), `2017 DOLS` = c(200L, 
200L, NA), `2017 UNITS` = c(2L, 1L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that and I am getting the following error:                                                 Error: Can't assign to elements that don't exist.
x Locations 882617, 2, 882618, 1765235, 2647851, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 1 element.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share data or part of it in reproducible format using which I can reproduce the above error? I cannot reproduce the error using the data in my post which is similar to what you have shared.

Comment: I presume the error is due to the large dimension of my data (I have over 700 000 observations). To see this I started running your code for a subset of lines. When I arrived to 90 000 I got the error message: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.8 Gb

Comment: I´ve been reducing the dimension to ballpark when the error appear, at 50 000 lines  I already get: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.9 Gb